How can I export giant mathematical equations as python functions?
My symbolic equation takes up 500 mb of memory on Mathematica and I would like to work with it on python, is there an easy way to export this so I don't take a month of my life typing it out? For a bit of context, there are only 12 variables in this giant equation, but it is nested under many many square roots, cube roots, theres a lot of fractions.

you could try how-to-export-expression-in-mathematica-to-python or try  ToPythonFunction there might be other ways.  You have ONE equation that is 500 MB?? wow, this must be world record of some sort.
